# why my url go to Google

Tags: java, android

I try to open Url in web browser but when I do it , the url go to Google

this is my Code :

```
String jokeUrl = "http://example.com/send.php?p1=" + deviceId + "&p2=" + strName + "&p3=" + Integer.toString(rate) + "&p4=";
String url = strComment;
url = url.replaceAll("\\n", "%0A");
url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
jokeUrl = jokeUrl + strComment;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(jokeUrl));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

for example when I write long text , it's going to Google but when I send short text it's normally.

my TextView for strComment :

```
  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/etComment"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="4dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:ems="10"
       android:maxLength="300"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:maxLines="5" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stated that URL string limit is of 2,000 characters. Check the `jokeUrl` size.

`Log.i("Joke Url Size", jokeUrl.length() + " is the size");`

For URL check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/3360307) post

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @user3722311 So the comment cannot be longer than 300 chars? Are there any other special characters in the URL string?

Comment: @DaveNewton my text have persian charecters ? when I write in text box is normally but when I copy the text and paste in textbox go to Google

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `URLEncoder.encode()` to encode all string parameters like `strComment` or `strName`.

For sending data to a backend, consider using a HTTP POST and not HTTP GET as implied by `ACTION_VIEW`. To send POST requests, use a HTTP stack and not an `Intent` like this.